# Do SQL Loader discards input data file after load completes

Tags: oracle12c, sql-loader

I'm loading data into Oracle DB using SQL Loader.
The input data files are FTP-ed from a remote location; I would like to preserve them, because re-extract is costly and complicated.
Is there any way to control what happens to the input data files after SQL Loader processed them?

Comment: SQL\*Loader doesn't delete the data file. Why do you think it does? Maybe you want a wrapper script around the `sqlldr` call to copy the file somewhere else to archive it (possibly adding a timestamp to the name)?

Comment: I just tried to find info about data file "lifecycle' in the documentation, but couldn't. Thanks, the wrapper approach will work, it will give me audit capacity.